# Converting a binary value stored as a string ("10011") to a byte representation (0b00010011) in Java?

Tags: java, binary

Odd question, but a framework I was provided contains a hash table where the return values are Strings. The strings are representative of binary values I need to work with. For example, I put in the key "F", and it will return a string with 0s and 1s, such as "10011". I need to work with that number, 10011, as binary, and eventually store it as binary. How do I go about turning "10011" into a byte 00010011?

Comment: Do you mean `(byte) Integer.parseInt(string, 2);` ?

Comment: Or `Byte.parseByte(string, 2)`?

Comment: Do you want a String `"0b00010011"` or an `int` or a `byte`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Integer.parseInt(String str, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), with `radix` being 2 for binary, 8 for octal, 10 for decimal and 16 for hexadecimal.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(binaryString, 2);
// Or use this if you prefer using byte
byte number = Byte.parseByte(binaryString, 2);
```

Comment: no, the user has a string, and he wants a byte

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the binary value fits into a byte.

Comment: This works, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int))  method of the `Integer` class. The radix is the base of your count system.

Answer (score 0):

`Integer.parseInt(input, 2)` example:

```
class ToBinary {
    public static void main( String ... args ) {
        String input = "10011";
        byte output = (byte) Integer.parseInt(input, 2);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```